# Flask: Execute time taking python script and direct the user to another page

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am building a flask application that prompts a user for his/her email and an input file. When the user enters them both, I run a script on this input file. Now this script takes a good amount of time to execute. I want to mail the result of this script evaluation to the user. However my page freezes for as long as the script is executing. I want my user to be able to go to another page displaying that his response has been submitted for processing and he shall be mailed it in a while, rather than him being stuck on the page for as long as the script executes. Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/

Comment: ain't you using threading? Yes celery is good option. But for a single task its a lot of work, instead you should use threading module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately used the `Threading module` made available in python, the implementation was quite simple, to generate a new thread that would take care of rendering the redirected page and the main thread would execute my script. If anybody needs it,

```
class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, params):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.h = i
        self.params = params
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        # do expensive work, your time taking script
```

and i would call it as:

```
thread1 = Mythread(1, params)
thread1.start()
return open('redirectpage.html')
```

This way my page wouldn't hang as long as the script runs

Comment: Hi @apoorva: Could you please elaborate the code a bit more? I cant wrap my head around it. What exactly is happening with the class Mythread?